One generic Angular app with different branding
I'm currently work on some Angular application where one of the requirement is to dynamically change background image, translations etc. based on query param (different tenant different branding). All assets should be placed in Azure blob storage (they are public so I have all links to assets already available - don't need to use SAS). As I don't have much experience in frontend I'm wondering what will be the best way to fulfill such requirements.
I was thinking about creating css for each tenant in azure container and load them depends on param value. But I'm not sure if its possible to change dynamically styles in Angular nor it's best way.

This is quite difficult to answer and might be to vague but here is a possible architecture for you branding.
Your application needs to be built with css tokens in mind and also translation tokens needs to be considered. These needs 2 different solutions but for the css you can use css variables and tokenise your application.
For example if you have the following
:root {
    --main-bg-color: brown;
}

body {
    background-color: var(--main-bg-color); 
}

For your different brands once you have retrieved the relevant color (in this example) you can try to override it in javascript like
// Get the root element
const root = document.documentElement;

// Update the --lightness value
root.style.setProperty('--main-bg-color', 'red');


Read more on:
css variables MDN
